# RealityKit – Difference between loading model using `.rcproject` vs `.usdz`

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm building a simple app that adds a hat on top of the user's face. I've seen examples of 2 different approaches:

1. Adding the object as a scene to `Experience.rcproject`
2. Reading the object from the bundle directly as a `.usdz` file

**Approach #1**

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        let arConfiguration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        
        uiView.session.run(arConfiguration,
                           options:[.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        
        let arAnchor = try! Experience.loadHat()
        
        uiView.scene.anchors.append(arAnchor)
    }
}
```

**Approach #2**

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "hat.usdz")
        
        modelEntity.position = SIMD3(0, 0, -8)
        modelEntity.orientation = simd_quatf.init(angle: 0, axis: SIMD3(-90, 0, 0))
        modelEntity.scale = SIMD3(0.02, 0.02, 0.02)
        
        arView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration())
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
        anchor.position.y += 0.25
        anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        let arConfiguration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        
        uiView.session.run(arConfiguration,
                           options:[.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        
        let fileName = "hat.usdz"
        let modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: fileName)
        
        modelEntity.position = SIMD3(0, 0, -8)
        modelEntity.orientation = simd_quatf.init(angle: 0, axis: SIMD3(-90, 0, 0))
        modelEntity.scale = SIMD3(0.02, 0.02, 0.02)
        
        let arAnchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
        arAnchor.addChild(modelEntity)
                
        uiView.scene.anchors.append(arAnchor)
    }
}
```

What is the main difference between these approaches? Approach #1 works, but the issue is that approach #2 doesn't even work for me - the object simply doesn't load into the scene. Could anyone explain a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you obtain the .usdz file?

Comment: @Yrb I managed to get it working now, just needed to downscale by a lot. But it's not attached to my face, it keeps floating AROUND my face. It seems like the anchor is not setup correctly. Are you seeing what may be wrong with that?

Is there a way to achieve EXACTLY THE SAME behaviour as in Experience.rcproject, just from the code? Like could I just copy the code from Experience? Is that accessible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `.rcproject` and `.usdz` is quite obvious: the Reality Composer file already has an anchor for the model (and it's at the top of the hierarchy). When you prototype in Reality Composer, you have the ability to visually control the scale of your models. `.usdz` models very often have a huge scale, which you need to reduce by 100 times.

As a rule, `.usdz` model doesn't have a floor, while `.rcproject` has a floor by default and this floor acts as a shadow catcher. Also, note that the `.rcproject` file is larger than the `.usdz` file.

```
let scene = try! Experience.loadHat()
arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)

print(scene)
```

When loading `.usdz` into a scene, you have to programmatically create an anchor (either ***swiftly*** or ***pythonically***). It also makes sense to use `.reality` files as they are optimized for faster loading.

```
let model = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "hat.usdz")
let anchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
anchor.addChild(model)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

print(model)
```

Also, put a face tracking config inside `makeUIView` method:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit 

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let model = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "hat.usdz")
    arView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration())
    
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
    anchor.position.y += 0.25
    anchor.addChild(model)
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    return arView
}
```

Also, check if the following render options are disabled.

```
arView.renderOptions = [.disableFaceMesh, .disablePersonOcclusion]
```

And check a position of pivot point in hat model.

Answer (score 0):

For approach number 2, try removing the the position for the modelEntity. You provided position as 0, -4.9 and 11.8. Those positions are in meters. So try to remove it and see if appears.

Comment: Yea I tried that, but it does not appear.. Do you have any other ideas why that would be?

Comment: Hm, I actually managed to get it working now, just needed to downscale by a lot. But it's not attached to my face, it keeps floating AROUND my face. It seems like the anchor is not setup correctly. Are you seeing what may be wrong with that?